# cannot find CKFinder.dll in ASP.NET packages

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, ckeditor, ckfinder

I took over an ASP.NET MVC project and can build and run it with MVC 5.2.3/.NET 4.5.2.

I can build and run it without problems. I am using the CKEdit (obviously with the CKFinder package included). The project has included a CKFinder.dll file in references. But in which package is that file included? I have created a test-project and installed almost every CKSource packages (including CKEditor and CKFinder) - without finding any CKFinder.dll. The only way to build the project has been copying the file from older versions of the project.

Is the file phased out?

Comment: Which version of CKFinder do you use?

Comment: Current Nuget-Package I use is CKFinder  3.4.1
The version of the CKFinder.dll is 2.4.1.2663

Comment: It looks like the older project used version 2 of CKFinder and this version is not available via NuGet (there's only version 3). For v2 you have to [download the package](https://cksource.com/ckfinder/download) (look for the latest [v2.6.1](https://download.cksource.com/CKFinder/CKFinder%20for%20ASP.NET/2.6.2/ckfinder_aspnet_2.6.2.zip) in CKFinder versions history) and add required dependencies manually.